# Problem with this question : uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Any ideas to solve this problem?

> Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}_{+} \to \mathbb{R}$ uniformly continuous. Prove that exists $K>0$ such that for each $x\in \mathbb{R}_{+},$ 
>   $$\sup_{w>0}\{ |f(x+w) -f(w)|\}\le K \,\, ( x + 1).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you hint instead of a complete answer since it's a homework question.

1. Let $F\colon\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R$ defined by $\displaystyle F(x)=\sup_{t>0}|f(x+t)-f(x)|$. Show that $F$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$.
2. Let $h\colon \mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R_+$ an uniformly continuous function on $\mathbb R_+$. Prove that we can find a constant $K>0$ such that $h(x)\leq K(x+1)$ for all $x\geq 0$.
3. Conclude.